# Estructura switch-case. ¿Los valores de los cases deben ser sí o sí valores únicos?

Tags: java, teoría

Pregunta de novato: ¿puedo usar una estructura de estas para poner un número de tipo entero dentro de la expresión que acompaña al `switch` y que los *cases* se activen cuando ese número se encuentre dentro de distintos rangos de valores determinados mediante el uso de operadores relacionales?

Edito con un ejemplo:

```
int expresion = 5;

switch (expresion) {
    case (expresion > 0):
        System.out.println("La expresión: " + expresion + "es mayor a cero");
        break; 
}
```

Es puramente teórica mi duda, para saber si puedo usar esta estructura en casos de comparación en vez de usar un `if-else`. En el ejemplo no se puede hacer así, pero es esa la idea.

Comment: Cuál estructura?

Comment: Estructura switch-case

Comment: @Bicho, lo dice el título, la estructura `switch-case`

Comment: @Skywalker, sugiero que pongas un ejemplo de lo que quisieras lograr

Comment: Depende mucho de los rangos que quieras evaluar. Pero no sería lo más apropiado en cuanto a la legibilidad del código. Yo optaría casi sin dudarlo por los `if`/`else`.

Comment: Ahí la edite con el ejemplo. Creo que lo que quiero hacer es poner de cabeza la funcionalidad del switch-case. Si o sí tendría que usar if/else.

Comment: Tu ejemplo con switch es: switch(expresion) { case 0: [print igual a 0]; break; default: [print mayor de 0]} La respuesta de DavElsanto lo deja claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias track3r, para estos casos usaré siempre el if/else no me queda duda ahora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No necesitas usar alguna expresión, sino entender bien cómo funciona un **switch** y el **break**.

```java
int x = 4;
switch(x) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Rango entre 0 y 1");
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Rango entre 2 y 3");
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Rango entre 4 y 6");
        break;
    default :
        System.out.println("otro rango");
}
```

Como puedes observar, en este caso el valor a imprimir va a ser `"Rango entre 4 y 6"`, dado que va a ingresar por el `case 4`, pero al tener el `break` en el `case 6` va a procesar desde `case 4` hasta `case 6` y terminará en esa instrucción, dado que existe un `break`, que indica al `switch` que debe terminar, es decir, salir de él.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias DavElsanto. Lo dejaste muy claro.